# Javascript swap function

Tags: javascript

I am a javascript beginner and I would like to create a function named swap that swaps the variables that were passed in:

```
function swap(a, b){
    var t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}
var x = 3;
var y = 4;
swap (x, y);
console.log(x + " " + y);
```

and the output should be `4 3`

but I can't figure out how to make this function work, because in C++ we would just pass the reference `swap(&a, &b)`. How to pass reference in JS?

Comment: Since you can't pass a reference to the variables in: no.

Comment: no, you can't, because there is no eqivalent for the `&` in `swap(&a, &b)`

Comment: C and javascript have different architecture. You should understand callback in javascript. C runs commands one by one. But javascript runs codes in bulk mode. The result can be caught by callback. Or you can use async and await mode in javascript.

Comment: function swap(a, b, callback){
     var t = a;
     a = b;
     b = t;
     callback(a, b);
 }

 var x = 3;
 var y = 4;

 swap (x, y, function(x, y){
  console.log(x + " " + y);
 })